# Pass more than one variable to a package.json script

Tags: node.js, npm, environment-variables, npm-scripts

I have in **package.json** (NOT BASH, NOT SH, NOT ZSHELL, NOT FISH).

So after we established the fact that this is my *package.json* file, let me present it to you:

## package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "NODE_ENV=myValue myProgram"
  }
```

I want to add more vars (e.g. `MYVAR=myOtherValue`) to above file, which is my *package.json* file. How can I do that (adding more vars to my package.json file)?

Let me be clear that I do not want to read the manpage of bash or zshell, or fish, or sh. This is why I put the question in here and did not read the manpage - otherwise I would not put it here and would have read the manpage. Thank you for understanding.

Comment: Space separated eg `NODE_ENV=myValue MYVAR=myOtherValue myProgram` see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26189662/how-set-multiple-env-variables-for-a-bash-command

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How set multiple env variables for a bash command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26189662/how-set-multiple-env-variables-for-a-bash-command)

Comment: Its not a duplicate. I am asking about nodeJs and package.json. From a Developer Standpoint (lets say I use Windows) this has nothing to do with bash at all. (Believe me we have 99% of Windows Developers who never heard of bash in their entire life and dont need to and dont want to)

Comment: Please don't reduce answers to just contain a one-liner. The additional information was provided to present context.

Comment: I did not ask about bash

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17978685/is-it-possible-to-set-multiple-environment-variables-in-one-cmd-line-statement/27901090

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your script should be:

```
"dev": "NODE_ENV=myValue MYVAR=myOtherValue myProgram"
```

as you can add multiple environment variables when space-separated.

This stems from the common behavior from terminals like bash, where you can set multiple env variables on the fly:

```
FOO1=baz FOO2=fnord FOO3=baz env | grep FOO
FOO1=baz
FOO2=fnord
FOO3=baz
```

Comment: I don't care about the gnu tools bash or grep in this question.

Comment: @nottinhill Fair point, yet it helps understanding why that approach works.

Answer (score -1):

I am with Stevek on this one,  I read the answer (the duplicate answer) and am frustrated with the references to bash.  I am on a windows system that uses Powershell.  I want to pass multiple environmental variables and have it work in windows systems using Powershell. Any reference to *nix commands etc unless to enable cross-system use is mudding the waters.

So far this answer is not answered. So will add what I found

This questions tells you how to pass 1 variable. [How to set environment variables from within package.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25112510/how-to-set-environment-variables-from-within-package-json)

```
 "start": "set NODE_ENV=YOURENV&&node start.js"
```

Now how to pass more than 1? That is still the question.

I was told that using cross-env is the best:
cross-env NODE_ENV=production my-command

The answer was given here: https://github.com/kentcdodds/cross-env/issues/15

```
"scripts": {
  "debug": "cross-env NODE_PATH=. DEBUG=app:* nodemon bootload.js"
}
```

However, cross-env does not use PowerShell but depreciate cmd shell on windows. So back to the main issue. [unless you make this change https://github.com/kentcdodds/cross-env/issues/192#issuecomment-513341729]